# How to let existing entries empty when using auto_now_add?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I added a field to my existing model :

```
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        blank=True, null=True)
```

The resulting file after makemigrations looks like

```
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='document',
        name='creation_date',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True),
    ),
```

When applying the migration, auto_now_add is applied to all existing entries.

How to avoid that ? creation_date must remain null for all data recorded before the migration is applied.

Comment: What does the migration file look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is probably to revert the migration, in the migration file. So you first run:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

but you do *not* (!) yet migrate. You can then inspect the migration file, and alter it to:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.2 on 2019-07-11 15:55

from django.db import migrations, models


def set_to_null(apps, schema_editor):
    SomeModel = apps.get_model("app", "SomeModel")
    SomeModel.objects.update(creation_date=None)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='somemodel',
            name='creation_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(set_to_null),
    ]
```

Then you thus can migrate your database. It will first construct an extra field, and then set the `creation_date` column, for existing records, with `set_to_null`, to `NULL`.

Comment: Does it means that django does't handle this out of the box ? I would have thought that it would be the default behaviour.

Comment: @Yvain: not as far as I know. I can not immediately find something in the documentation, although of course I do not know the documentation "exhaustively".