# Django: nullable DateTimeField populates with the current timestamp?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-2.2

In my model I've added a `DatetimeField` like this:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

However, after running the migration all existing rows appear to have `created` set to the current timestamp. I want all existing rows to have `created` = NULL upon migration. How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56992825/67579

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in two stages. Firstly create the field without auto_now_add and make that migration, which will create it as default for everyone. Then, add auto_now_add back, and create another migration, which will set it as the default for all items going forward.

Comment: This worked, thanks. Is this behavior documented somewhere? I find it somewhat unobvious/confusing.

Comment: What behaviour? What is confusing?

Comment: From the docs on [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add): `Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.` No objects are created here, so shouldn't the field just be set to NULL (the implicit default)?

Answer (score 0):

You might have provided the `default` value to current timestamp. So, after you run migration it updated all existing records with current timestamp.

So, set default to `None` in the created migration file.

Comment: I do want the field to be set to now for *new* records. But setting it to now for existing records doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @planetp update your migration file in the question.